# Find unique field id when inserting records

Tags: php, mysql, unique, unique-key

Is there a way to insert records into a Unique field without duplicating the record. If the record exists I need to use the record id for reference in another table. I'm using php and mySql.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column named "id" of type "INT" and set it "primary key" and "auto increment" in phpmyadmin for example.

This way you will have a unique field starting at 1 and counting for each new record in the table, you can then reference its value in other tables.

Comment: ok, sorry maybe i didn't make my self clear, I already have this. What I want to do is to insert records in that table. Some of the records may already exist, its a tbl containing tags. If i attempt to insert a record that exists I need to use the existing record id for reference in another table. Hope this is more clear, thanks for reply.

Comment: why not doing a first SELECT query to check wether the record already exists or not, and then doing the INSERT query if needed?

Comment: the insert is not the problem, it inserts fine I need to grab the id of the existing unique field.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If a table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) inserts or updates a row, the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function returns the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. Exception: For updates, [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is not meaningful prior to MySQL 5.1.12. However, you can work around this by using [`LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Suppose that `id` is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. To make [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
> ```